# Issue when comparing result of to_char(myDate, 'DAY') to a string

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I have been trying to find what the issue might be but I am just out of luck and don't understand this problem at all.I have the following code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ckeckDay(dateC in date)
RETURN VARCHAR
IS
  day VARCHAR(15);
  checkFriday VARCHAR(1);
BEGIN
  checkFriday := 'N';
  day := to_char(dateC, 'DAY');
  IF day = 'FRIDAY' THEN
    checkFriday := 'Y';
  END IF;
  RETURN day;
END;
/
```

the `dateC` is set to Friday (even tested it by returning `day` instead of the `day` variable and it returns Friday.) However the `IF` statement never evaluates to true even though the `day` variable is indeed Friday.Any ideas how to go around this issue.Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is because `day` variable contains a blank padded value. Use `trim` function to get rid of leading and trailing spaces:

```
IF trim(day) = 'FRIDAY' THEN
  checkFriday := 'Y';
END IF;
```

And please use `VARCHAR2` datatype for string variables. Do not use `VARCHAR`.

Comment: Thanks allot for your answer.It worked perfectly.Also thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 10):

If you want to be really robust about this then you ought to force the NLS setting to English and apply the "fill mode" format model FM for trimming leading and trailing spaces.

```
If To_Char(DateC,'fmDAY', 'nls_date_language=english') = 'FRIDAY'
Then ...
```

Comment: Thanks,will make use of that too.