# Retrieving last monday but no data in result set

Tags: oracle11g

I am trying to retrieve last monday when given date is monday below is the code.

```
select
  Case 
     when
       to_char(to_date('21/10/2013','dd/mm/yyyy'), 'DAY') = 'MONDAY' 
     then to_date(next_day(to_date('21/10/2013','dd/mm/yyyy')-7,'Tuesday') - 1, 'dd/mm/yyyy')
  END 
from dual
```

Query is executing and result is one record but record is totally empty.

I am confused why there is no data in the result set.

Please help me in resolving this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Issue when comparing result of to\_char(myDate, 'DAY') to a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13269676/issue-when-comparing-result-of-to-charmydate-day-to-a-string)

Comment: Also, return type of NEXT_DAY is `date`. So you shouldn't use to_date function on it. Probably you want to use to_char.

Comment: @Ramblin Man thanks for your reply.. Changed to to_char still the result is same.

Comment: Thanks @Ramblin Man that link worked for me. Post it in answer I will mark it as answered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used `Trim` before the statement and that resolved the issue.

```
trim(to_char(to_date(SYSDATE,'dd/mm/yyyy'), 'DAY')) = 'MONDAY'
```