# Name of day padded with spaces prevent proper behavior

Tags: if-statement, plsql, varchar2, in-operator

I'm trying to go in a if condition in PLSQL when certaint dates are on a specific day in the week.

```
DECLARE
  v_gebDatum    CONSTANT     DATE                 := to_date('21-01-1995', 'dd-MM-yyyy');
  v_mathDatum                DATE                 := v_gebDatum;
  v_huidigeDag               VARCHAR2(20);

  v_teller                   number   := 0;
BEGIN
  WHILE to_char(v_mathDatum, 'yyyy') < to_char(sysdate, 'yyyy')
  LOOP
    v_mathDatum := add_months(v_mathDatum, 12);
    v_huidigeDag := to_char(v_mathDatum, 'DAY');
    dbms_output.put_line(v_huidigeDag);
    IF v_huidigeDag IN('ZATERDAG', 'ZONDAG')
    THEN
      dbms_output.put_line(v_mathDatum);
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Problem is that I can't get this to work. When printing the v_huidigeDag it clearly has the values 'ZATERDAG and 'ZONDAG' in some of the printed lines.

It appears that, for some reason when I printed the values for daynames the program added spaces in. I guess it takes the char length for the longest day name ('DONDERSDAG') in my Locale. And everything with less characters than that it adds spaces. So zaterdag becomes = 'ZATERDAG ' and zondag becomes = 'ZONDAG '. Now it's working but does somebody know an easy way to prevent this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Issue when comparing result of to\_char(myDate, 'DAY') to a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13269676/issue-when-comparing-result-of-to-charmydate-day-to-a-string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the `DAY` format. According to the [date format documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm#sthref413):

> **DAY**
>
> Name of day, **padded with blanks to display width of the widest name of day** in the date language used for this element.

To disable that behavior, you have to use the [`FM` modifier](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm#sthref463):

> **FM**
>
> In a datetime format element of a TO_CHAR function, this modifier suppresses blanks in subsequent character elements (such as MONTH) and suppresses leading zeroes for subsequent number elements (such as MI) in a date format model. **Without FM, the result of a character element is always right padded with blanks to a fixed length**, and leading zeroes are always returned for a number element. **With FM, which suppresses blank padding, the length of the return value may vary**.

In your particular case:

```
    v_huidigeDag := to_char(v_mathDatum, 'fmDAY');
```