# pl-sql it can't compare two string ? why

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
declare 
  v_date varchar2(15);
begin 
  v_date := to_char(sysdate, 'DAY');
  if upper(v_date) = to_char('TUESDAY') then
     dbms_output.put_line('Today is Tuesday');
  else 
     dbms_output.put_line('Today is not tuesday'|| upper(v_date) );
  end if ;
end;
```

Comment: Whats your question?  Syntax error?  Always doing the else clause?...

Comment: try this: v_date := trim(to_char(sysdate, 'DAY'));

Answer (score 1):

Please trim the value you get from to_char of day then you should get correct result

```
declare 
  v_date varchar2(15);
begin 
  v_date := to_char(sysdate, 'DAY');
  if trim(v_date) = 'TUESDAY' then
     dbms_output.put_line('Today is Tuesday');
  else 
     dbms_output.put_line('Today is not tuesday '|| v_date );
  end if ;
end;
```

Comment: Strangely `TRIM` is required

Comment: I donno........Why blank padding?

Comment: Actually we get space after fetching day value from date,  I think to_char for day is having some fixed length like char,  thats why its add spaces to fulfill its length

Comment: Yeah...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13269676/issue-when-comparing-result-of-to-charmydate-day-to-a-string . If `To_Char( v_date,'fmDAY', 'nls_date_language=english') = 'TUESDAY'`  is an alternative to `TRIM`