# Using Attendance Log file from fingerprint device. How to show present and absents?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I get this file from fingerprint log from device :

```
Id User_id      PuchTime
--------------------------
1   152      2018-07-17 09:38:03
2   184      2018-07-17 16:56:43
3   152      2018-07-17 16:57:18
4   165      2018-07-17 16:57:43
5   70       2018-07-17 16:57:59
6   134      2018-07-17 16:58:28
7   276      2018-07-17 16:59:04
8   278      2018-07-17 16:59:05
9   271      2018-07-17 16:59:10
10  268      2018-07-17 16:59:13
11  284      2018-07-17 16:59:16
12  364      2018-07-17 16:59:35
13  19       2018-07-17 16:59:38
14  381      2018-07-17 17:01:12
15  73       2018-07-17 17:12:31
16  126      2018-07-17 17:12:36
17  382      2018-07-17 17:13:50
18  53       2018-07-18 06:34:13
19  284      2018-07-18 08:05:17
```

How can I make a query in Postgres query to extract the data look like this:

```
User_id  Check_Date   TimeIN    TimeOUT   Hours   status
--------------------------------------------------------
152      2018-07-17    09:38:03 16:56:43  7.8     present
152      2018-07-18                               Absent
```

i use this query

```
SELECT userid, name, CAST(PuchTime as DATE) Check_Date, 
to_char(PuchTime, 'day') days,
       MIN(CAST(PuchTime as Time)) TimeIN, 
       MAX(Cast(PuchTime as Time)) TimeOUT,
       CAST(MAX(PuchTime) - MIN(PuchTime) AS Time) As hour
FROM attendance_FHLHR
GROUP BY userid,name, CAST(PuchTime as DATE), to_char(PuchTime, 'day')
order by name DESC, check_date ASC, userid ASC

Output of my query:
```

i need status and hour calculation.

```
    User_id  Check_Date   TimeIN    TimeOUT   Hours
    -----------------------------------------------
    152      2018-07-17    09:38:03 16:56:43  7:18:40  
    152      2018-07-18
```

Comment: Can you please add the output that your current query creates and tell us where it differs from what you need?

Comment: Please don't tag 3 entirely different RDBMS (MySQL, SQL Server and PostgreSQL). Tag only the one relevant to your question. This is, however, clearly not SQL Server, as `to_char` is not a valid T-SQL function.

Comment: @Corion check output of my query.

Comment: @Larnu postgresql i am using.

Comment: Then don't tag mysql.

Comment: @amnaKalsoom Maybe you want to explain how you get from 7:18 to 7.8 - most likely it is because you are calculating fractional hours, but you will need to explain the rule how to calculate this. The rest is mostly left-joining the table against a calendar table to get a list of all (work)days and their timestamps.

Comment: @Corion rule is per day calculation.
i have just 1 table to show you record (punchtime).
there is any other way to show ?

Answer (score 0):

You need a reference set of dates and users to compare the activities against. Generating this is not trivial in any programming language, and particularly so with SQL. But you could use the list of dates/users you already have, with a cartesian join to the list of users:

```
SELECT alldatesusers.userid, alldatesusers.ref_date AS check_date
,  TimeIn, TimeOut, hour
FROM
(SELECT DISTINCT CAST(rd.PuchTime as DATE) AS refdate, user.userid
  FROM attendance_FHLHR rd
  , (SELECT DISTINCT ru.userid
     FROM attendance_FHLHR ru) AS user
) AS alldatesusers
LEFT JOIN
( SELECT userid, name, CAST(PuchTime as DATE) Check_Date
  ,to_char(PuchTime, 'day') days
  ,MIN(CAST(PuchTime as Time)) TimeIN 
  ,MAX(Cast(PuchTime as Time)) TimeOUT
  ,CAST(MAX(PuchTime) - MIN(PuchTime) AS Time) As hour
  FROM attendance_FHLHR
  GROUP BY userid,name, CAST(PuchTime as DATE), to_char(PuchTime, 'day')
) AS attendance
ON alldatesusers.refdate=attendance.Check_date
AND alldates.userid=attendance.userid
```

Comment: Generating a list of dates is extremely easy in Postgres using `generate_series()`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: if it is easy perhaps you could offer an answer using it as the base of your implementation

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name yes please some thing can you show your query,.

Answer (score 0):

The following SQL uses `generate_series()` to create a calendar and uses the list of existing workers from the punch card table as a list of users. Cross-joining this gives a list of dates and users, from which you can easily derive absence/presence.

Converting the minutes worked to fractional hours is left as an exercise to the reader.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/24e39/30)

#### SQL

```
with workers as ( select distinct user_id from clock)
, calendar as (
    select workday from 
    generate_series(
           (date '2018-07-01')::timestamp,
           (date '2018-07-31')::timestamp,
           interval '1 day') workday
)
SELECT w.user_id, workday, 
       to_char(cast(PuchTime as DATE), 'day') days,
       MIN(CAST(PuchTime as Time)) TimeIN, 
       MAX(Cast(PuchTime as Time)) TimeOUT,
       CAST(MAX(PuchTime) - MIN(PuchTime) AS Time) As hour
FROM
  calendar cross join workers w
  left join clock c
    on workday = CAST(c.PuchTime as DATE)
         and w.user_id=c.user_id
GROUP BY w.user_id, workday, calendar.*, CAST(c.PuchTime as DATE)
order by w.user_id DESC, calendar ASC
```

#### Results (abridged)

```
user_id     workday             days    timein  timeout     hour
382     2018-07-01T00:00:00Z    (null)  (null)  (null)  (null)
382     2018-07-02T00:00:00Z    (null)  (null)  (null)  (null)
382     2018-07-03T00:00:00Z    (null)  (null)  (null)  (null)
382     2018-07-04T00:00:00Z    (null)  (null)  (null)  (null)
382     2018-07-05T00:00:00Z    (null)  (null)  (null)  (null)
...
152     2018-07-16T00:00:00Z    (null)  (null)  (null)  (null)
152     2018-07-17T00:00:00Z    tuesday     09:38:03    16:57:18    07:19:15
152     2018-07-18T00:00:00Z    (null)  (null)  (null)  (null)
152     2018-07-19T00:00:00Z    (null)  (null)  (null)  (null)
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming every employee doesn't show up absent for the same day, this should work:

```
with from_thru as (
  select
    min (punchtime)::date as from_date, 
    max (punchtime)::date as thru_date
  from attendance_FHLHR
),
users as (
  select distinct user_id from attendance_FHLHR
)
select
  gs.date::date, u.user_id, min (a.punchtime) as TimeIn,
  max (a.punchtime) as TimeOut,
  extract (epoch from max (a.punchtime) - min (a.punchtime))/3600 as Hours,
  case
    when min (a.punchtime) is null then 'Absent'
    when count (1) = 1 then 'Missing Punch'
    else 'Present'
  end as status
from
  from_thru
  cross join generate_series (from_date, thru_date, interval '1 day') gs (date)
  cross join users u
  left join attendance_FHLHR a on
    a.punchtime::date = gs.date and
    a.user_id = u.user_id
group by
  gs.date, u.user_id
```

I also added a condition called 'Missing Punch' in cases where there is only a single punch.

-- EDIT 11/2/2018 --

Per your feedback on the "off days" table, here is a fix I think would accommodate that as well.  Note no changes on the subqueries should be necessary:

```
select
  gs.date::date, u.user_id, min (a.checktime) as TimeIn,
  max (a.checktime) as TimeOut,
  extract (epoch from max (a.checktime) - min (a.checktime))/3600 as Hours,
  case
    when o.userid is not null then 'Off Day'
    when min (a.checktime) is null then 'Absent'
    when count (1) = 1 then 'Missing Punch'
    else 'Present'
  end as status
from
  from_thru
  cross join generate_series (from_date, thru_date, interval '1 day') gs (date)
  cross join users u
  left join off_days o on
    extract (dow from gs.date)::text = o.days and
    u.user_id = o.userid
  left join attendance_FHLHR a on
    a.checktime::date = gs.date and
    a.user_id = u.user_id
group by
  gs.date, u.user_id, o.userid
```

Comment: Awsome Man. champion

Comment: if we have other table where users have off days. then what i do in query?

Comment: Can you modify your question to include an example?  I kind of understand but want to be sure I am answering the right question.

Comment: check please this link. i explain my query . in this query days are repeat.
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=fe6ed0c3d85582ec37c003a599c9886d

Comment: thnaks i modify your query and done. check my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

**DISCLAIMER**: (This one is for both: this one here and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53077777))

[demo: db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=c3a88cf881c9d4f5ffc6e83f23e90af3)

---

```
WITH dates AS(                                                   -- 1
    SELECT
        min(checktime)::date as min,
        max(checktime)::date as max
    FROM log
)

SELECT 
    user_id,
    check_date::date,
    -- 4: 
    CASE WHEN checktime::date = check_date THEN checktime::time  ELSE NULL END as time_in,
    CASE WHEN checktime::date = check_date THEN time_out::time ELSE NULL END as time_out,
    CASE WHEN checktime::date = check_date THEN (time_out - checktime)::time ELSE NULL END as hours
FROM (
    SELECT
        user_id,
        checktime,
        lead(checktime) OVER (ORDER BY checktime) as time_out,  -- 2
        generate_series(                                        -- 3
            (SELECT min FROM dates), 
            (SELECT max FROM dates), 
            interval '1 day'
        ) as check_date
    FROM log
)s
ORDER BY user_id, check_date
```

1. Calculate the min/max date thresholds of your log to get bounds for date generating
2. `lead` [window function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html) takes the next `checktime` value to the current row. So the next `checktime` counts as `time_out`
3. `generate_series` generates all date values between given (calculated) bounds
4. `CASE` parts: If the current `checktime` equals not the generated date value then give out `NULL`; else give out the current `time_in` / `time_out` / time difference

---

Concerning the nearly duplicated expanded question: [Using Attendance Log and OFF days Table . How to show present ,absents and OFF day?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53077777) I am adding the answer here because the duplication should be closed and the question above should be expanded.

**demo, see second part of fiddle above**

```
WITH dates AS(
    SELECT
        min(checktime)::date as min,
        max(checktime)::date as max
    FROM log
)
SELECT DISTINCT ON (user_id, check_date, time_in)   -- 6
    user_id, 
    check_date, 
    to_char(check_date, 'Day') as day,              -- 2
    COALESCE(time_in,                               -- 4
         MAX(time_in) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id, check_date ORDER BY time_out NULLS LAST)
    ) as time_in, 
    time_out, 
    hours,
    CASE                                            -- 5
        WHEN checktime::date = check_date THEN 'present' 
        WHEN of.days IS NOT NULL THEN 'OFF DAY'
        ELSE 'absent'
    END as status
FROM (
    SELECT 
        user_id,
        check_date,
        checktime,
        CASE WHEN checktime::date = check_date THEN checktime::time  ELSE NULL END as time_in,
        CASE WHEN checktime::date = check_date THEN time_out::time ELSE NULL END as time_out,
        -- 1
        CASE WHEN checktime::date = check_date THEN extract(epoch FROM (time_out - checktime)) / 60 / 60 ELSE NULL END as hours
    FROM (
        SELECT
            user_id,
            checktime,
            lead(checktime) OVER (ORDER BY checktime) as time_out,
            generate_series(
                (SELECT min FROM dates), 
                (SELECT max FROM dates), 
                interval '1 day'
            ) as check_date
        FROM log
    ) s
) s
--- 3
LEFT JOIN off_days of ON (of.userid = s.user_id) AND (of.days = trim(to_char(check_date, 'day')))
ORDER BY user_id, check_date
```

Because it this is a expansion of the previous query I explain only the changes:

1. Instead of giving the time difference as `time`, a `numeric` value is needed. So [`extract(epoch...)`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html) gets the seconds of the difference which are converted into hours by `/ 60 / 60`
2. [Converting a date into a weekday](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/functions-formatting.html) with `to_char` function
3. Joining the off_day table against the `user_id` and the the week day (again using the `to_char` function, this time with small capitals). [`to_char` adds whitespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13269676/issue-when-comparing-result-of-to-charmydate-day-to-a-string) - so `trim()` removes it for the comparison
4. Tricky part (together with 6): Because the join duplicates the rows, it is necessary to eliminate the wrong ones. It is not possible to do a simple `DISTINCT` on `user_id` and week day because e.g. `152` has two entries on one day. But because `53` has two entries on different days (in my example, see fiddle) for both dates a valid and an empty row is created. This code line duplicats the `time_in` value into the empty row (next step see (6))
5. If there's an entry for the generated date (see first part above) it is `present`. If not, check if is an "off day", otherwise `absent`
6. We have the cases: A: no duplicated rows; B: two rows per user_id and week day because there are two entries; C: two rows (with empty times) because of the join. We want no duplicate rows, so there's the `distinct`. This works also for (C) because we duplicated the `time_in` for the `NULL` rows in (4)

Comment: Next time, please:
Simplify your example very much! There are too many entries in your example without any reason (no new information or new use cases)

Comment: Please try to separate your problems. There are many many many different steps here (How to get the next value into the current row? How the get a time difference? How to convert time to Day or hours? How to join a table? How to make difference between the status? How to get a date range into the query?)

Comment: If you have an additional question it is ok to ask it by expanding the question. But if it a new question please build a new simplified example. In your case both questions have to solve the main problem first before expanding. So please be clear: What do you want to ask precisely. Stackoverflow is no cheap platform to solve your whole problems.

Comment: If someone helped you, please do not forget to accept and upvote their answers. All people here invested their time into helping you. Accepting shows that the problem is already solved so it is not necessary anymore to think about it; Upvoting honors the work (it counts into some statistical points)